# Not obtaining the correct output for the following code

Tags: java, output

I'm curious as to why the output for the following code is 14 1. When I go through the code myself, I'm ending up with `counter` being equal to 2, and `count` being equal to 4. I want to make sure that we are only printing the second index, so we only go through the loop two times, right?

```
 package mix4;

public class Mix4 {

    int counter = 0; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0; 
        Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20]; 
        int x = 0; 
        while(x < 9) {
            m4a[x] = new Mix4();
            m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1; 
            count = count + 1; 
            count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
            x = x + 1; 
        }
        System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
    }

        public static int maybeNew(int index) {
            if (index < 5) {
                Mix4 m4 = new Mix4(); 
                m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code in your if statement does nothing

```
Mix4 m4 = new Mix4(); 
m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
```

`m4` immediately goes out of scope and is not used.

Your code could be changed to

```
count = count + maybeNew(x);  // static method
```

and `maybeNew` is the same as

```
if (index < 5) {
        return 1;
    }

return 0;
```

**not** sure what logic you are wanting, but this is the logic you have wrote

Comment: I definitely realized that that section of code was useless, however, this is a code in a textbook, and they are trying to show the use of references.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, regardless, it will return 1.

Comment: Only if `x` is less than `5`

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`mayBeNew` is a static method. So the following

```
count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
```

is no different than

```
count = count + Mix4.maybeNew(x);
// or
count = count + maybeNew(x);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the while loop, count is increasing by one for 9 times and becomes 9. maybeNew method's if part runs for 5 times and increases the count 5. After 5, it does not affect the count since it is returning 0. Every turn for the while loop, you are creating a new object and it has initial counter=0, then program increases it by 1. maybeNew method does not affect the counter because it creates another object and it is not written or saved to the objects on the array. All of the objects in your array has counter=1 for this reason.

Comment: I don't see how count is increasing by 1, the same value, everytime it goes through the loop. The way I see it, count starts out with 0, so when we go through in the first loop, we get 1, then we add count with the value we get from maybeNew(X), which is 1, and I'm getting 2.

Comment: For the first 5 iteration on the while loop, at the line "count = count + 1; ", program increases count by 1 and at the line "count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);" program increases count by 1 too because maybeNew function returns 1. After then maybeNew method returns 0 and it does not affect count. Count will be increased by 1 for 4 times and count will be 14 at the end. I tried to give the parts that changed the count partially. First iteration makes count 2, second 4, third 6, fourth 8, fifth 10, sixth 11 .... ninth 14.

Comment: Thank you so much. Showing how count changed partially really helped. I think I got messed up initially when reaching the print statement. I realized that the looking at the first index was only for the counter variable.

Comment: You are welcome. You can use debugging to see which lines change a specific variable.